# Grease Pencil stroke disappears

Tags: grease-pencil

Everytime I press <kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> I see the pencil as cursor and the indication that I'm about to draw something, but every time I draw a line, the line disappears.

Comment: You need to give a lot more information...for example, what pencil (I am guessing grease pencil).

Comment: Yes grease pencil. It was working until I switched to Object mode.

Comment: You mean you were in Grease Pencil mode?

Comment: Are you using the RetopoFlow add-on by any chance? If so sometimes grease pencil won't work on an active object. You might have to export the object then reimport it. I was having the same issue and that was one fix.

Comment: If your object is set to x-ray mode, the grease pencil marks will vanish.

Comment: You probably drew on a different frame of animation.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure you don't have the [Grease Pencil layers] and [Grease Pencil Colors] set to invisible (eye icon).  I spent an hour trying to figure out why, but forgot that I turned them off.

For the new players:
N to open the right hand menu.
Uncollapse the  ▼ ☑Grease Pencil and ▼Grease Pencil Colors
Look to make sure the eyes are visible for both layers.  Also try creating a new Grease Pencil layer and seeing if that fixes any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Double check the opacity of the active layer. If it's set to zero, the created stroke won't be shown after drawing, by it will be visible when drawing

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a 3D mouse for zooming, so my grease pencil drawing planes are created in weird angles. As a quick fix, I set *Scale Y* to $0$.

When I then draw a stroke, it instantly shrinks to an invisible point at the drawing plane origin.

This does not happen, if I set *Scale Y* to $0.001$

[image: Scale Y set to zero]

Edit:

Just found a better way to fix the grease pencil drawing plane angle.
Change the option at the top of the drawing window from *View* to *Front (X-Z)*.

[image]

Comment: Had this same issue and fixed by setting y-scale to non-zero.  Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that `X-Ray` mode is disabled on the object you are drawing on. Having it on will make the object's geometry draw on top of any grease pencil strokes you make on it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem today.Maybe you pressed H accidentally. Go to the edit Mode and then try press Alt+H see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that you didn't accidentally go to a new frame in the dope sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, and not fixed. Try installing the new version of blender. I have two different blenders installed on my pc, and one always has the bug while the other doesn't. So reinstalling or updating will fix the bug I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is that `Thickness Scale` is near 0 for that layer.
Try to increase the value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was that the Grease Pencil stroke was created at a specific point in the timeline, so just grab the time marker and check in which frame the strokes were created.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and found that it was caused by being in *Wireframe* shading mode. I just switched from *Wireframe* to *Solid* and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, turned out I was drawing on a frame that was within the boundary of ithe Time Offset modifier.

The strokes would show up in *Edit Mode*, but seemed to disappear while in *Draw Mode*.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a mac mini m1 and I had this issue while I tried upgrading to 3.2.1 from 3.1.2 but this seems to have been occuring intermittently and leaves me with no clue if I have done anything wrong.

Solution: I updated my version with 2.93.9 LTS version and this has resolved the issue for me.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe in somehow your stroke keyframe location changed!

check the time line or the dope sheet, i found mine in 173