# Problem, when I redraw on a grease pencil layer new strokes doesn't appear above old stroke

Tags: color, layers, grease-pencil

I'm trying to remake a grease pencil file and I forgot one little shading detail on the body part. I then went back to add the shading on said layer but it appears under it instead of over it. How can I fix this? See the images below. I'm 100% positive it is on the same layer.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter **Edit Strokes** mode, and in tool panel you will find this menu:

[image]

It orders selected strokes inside layer.

Comment: Is it possible to update this answer for 2.8? I'm a bit of a noob but as far as I know semantic 'layers' are now 'collections' and most menus are moved around

Answer (score 0):

My scenario is a bit different as I am not using grease pencil for anything except annotation, but I had a very similar problem

I am working in 2.8 and for me it worked to press `n` as suggested [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101167/79197); instead of it saying anything about 'grease pencil', at the bottom of the 'view' tab there was an 'Annotations' drop-down.

In the drop-down was my existing annotation layer, if I added a new layer above the existing and drew on that everything stayed intact with my original annotation. Hurrah!

I would imagine that for your specific scenario (whilst working in 2.8) a better reference would be the blender docs [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/properties/data.html#d-layers), but this is only if you can enter into edit mode on your grease pencil lines, which I couldn't because they belonged to the edit mode context of an object for me.

[image: Location]